# Improving Ruby Socket Performance

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, openssl

I am making a socket connection using TLS1.2 and and noticing a bunch of latency in reading data from the socket. I suspect it has something to do with Nagle algorithm and I'm trying to disable it on client and server but with not much luck.

```
socket = TCPSocket.open(host,port)
socket.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, Socket::TCP_NODELAY, 1) # Nagle algorithm
ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ssl_context.ssl_version = :SSLv23
ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(socket, ssl_context)
ssl_socket.sync_close = true
ssl_socket.connect

request = "some_data"

ssl_socket.puts(request)

while( c = ssl_socket.accept )
     c.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, Socket::TCP_NODELAY, 1)
     while( m = c.gets )
         c.puts( m.chomp )
     end
end


# The while loop above is currently failing, need help with it
# Here is the loop that is working but latency is 15-20 seconds

while line = ssl_socket.gets
     p line
end


ssl_socket.close
```

Comment: If you just ping the server with the `ping` command from a terminal what is the normal latency and what is the latency you see in your ruby scripts?

Comment: So I can't really use ping in this case since I'm connecting to a specific port. But round trip is taking me 10-20 seconds for the above code snippet. And according to the vendor their response times for my request are in the ms range.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that a _round trip_ _taking_ _10-20 seconds_ _has something to do with Nagle algorithm_.